# Validation in activeadmin with custom controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, controller, activeadmin

In our web app, a *composition* has many *authors* through a table named *contributions*. We want to check that an admin does not accidentally delete all the authors of one composition in activeadmin (at least one should remain). If this happens, the update fails with an error message and the edit view for a composition is rendered again.

Calling the model validation with

```
validates_presence_of :authors, on: :update
```

is not suitable here, because the addition of new contributions (thus authors) is done while calling the `success.html` on the update function of the activeadmin controller, to prevent some previous bugs that created double entries for authors.

Models are:

```
class Composition < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contributions
  has_many :authors, through: :contributions
end
----
class Contribution < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :composition
  belongs_to :author
end
----
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :author_roles, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :contributions
  has_many :compositions, through: :contributions
end
```

Our code in admin has some background logic to handle what has been described before:

```
ActiveAdmin.register admin_resource_name = Composition do
  ...
  controller do
    def update
      author = []
      contribution_delete = []
      params[:composition][:authors_attributes].each do |number, artist|
        if artist[:id].present?
          if artist[:_destroy] == "1"
            cont_id = Contribution.where(author_id: artist[:id],composition_id: params[:id]).first.id
            contribution_delete << cont_id
          end  
        else
          names = artist[:full_name_str].strip.split(/ (?=\S+$)/)
          first_name = names.size == 1 ? '' : names.first
          exist_author = Author.where(first_name: first_name, last_name: names.last, author_type: artist[:author_type]).first
          author << exist_author.id if exist_author.present?
        end
      end if params[:composition][:authors_attributes] != nil
      params[:composition].delete :authors_attributes
      update! do |success, failure|
        success.html do
          if author.present?
            author.each do |id|
              Contribution.create(author_id: id, composition_id: params[:id])
            end
          end  

          if contribution_delete.present?
            contribution_delete.each do |id|
              Contribution.find(id).destroy
            end
          end
          ...
          redirect_to admin_composition_path(@composition.id)
        end
        failure.html do
          render :edit
        end
      end
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Do you have any idea how I can control the `authors_attributes` and throw a flash message like "There must be at least one author" if the number of to-be-deleted authors is equal to the number of existing authors?

I thought maybe it's possible to handle this before the `update!` call so to convert the success into a failure somehow, but I have no idea how.